# Existence of approximate Nash equilibrium (continuous game)

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

My question concerns continuous games $((S_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n}, (u_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n})$, where $S_i$ are (continuous) compact strategy sets and $u_i$ denotes the utility function of agent $i$.

From [Glicksberg's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glicksberg%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20the%20study%20of%20zero,games%20have%20a%20minimax%20value%20.&text=where%20f%20and%20g%20run,measures%20on%20A%20and%20B.), we know that if the utility functions $u_i$ are continuous in the agents' strategies, then there exists a (mixed) Nash equilibrium. However, my question is rather about the general existence of [$\varepsilon$-Nash equlibria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon-equilibrium).

*Is it true that any continuous game with compact strategy sets posses an $\varepsilon$-Nash equilibrium for all $\varepsilon > 0$?*

Note that no continuity of the utilities $u_i$ has been assumed here.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, unless I am misreading something, [the game referenced in the Glicksberg's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_without_a_value) wikipedia page does not have an $\epsilon$-equilibrium.

Quoting the game here for completeness:

"Here is the game:
Players I and II choose numbers x and y respectively, between 0 and 1.  The payoff to player I is
$$K(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
  -1 & \text{if } x<y<x+1/2,  \\
   0 & \text{if } x=y \text{ or } y=x+1/2,\\
   1 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$"

and also

"There is no epsilon equilibrium for sufficiently small $\varepsilon$." (as the minmax is 3/7 and maxmin is 1/3.)

Comment: How did they compute these mysteriious ratios $3/7$ and $1/3$?